# What kind of plant/bush/whatever is this?

Tags: identification

This has been growing in my flower bed for a a couple of months.  It sprouted up by itself.  I don't know how it got there on anything about it.  Hope someone recognizes it.[image]

Comment: what part of the world do you live in?

Comment: This belongs to Phytolacca genus. For an accurate identification of species belonging to this genus, count the number of stamens and take a close-up picture of one of the fruits.

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be **Phytolacca americana**, commonly known as Pokeweed, which does pop up all on its own, see the following article for more information:  [Pokeweed, American (Phytolacca americana): The Jekyll and Hyde Plant](http://nadiasyard.com/our-native-plants/american-pokeweed/).

Comment: And it should be added: very invasive in some region.

Comment: This is actually the 8th time this plant has been asked about here (closing as duplicate). I think we should propose a pokeweed identification Stack Exchange site

Answer (score 0):

Some people also call it poke sallet. I think the berries are toxic.